# Dbus function with a OUT (sbb) param

Tags: python, dbus

I would like to call a DBus function with Python3. I made an introspection on it :

```
<method name="GetItemStatus">
  <arg name="absolutePath" direction="in" type="s" />
  <arg name="status" direction="out" type="(sbb)" />
</method>
```

The first param is a simple string, it's ok, but I don't know how to send the second one (status)...

Could someone help me please ?

Seb

Answer (score 0):

It's ok, I found the solution :o)

```
session_bus = dbus.SessionBus()
hubic_account_obj = session_bus.get_object('com.hubiC', 
'/com/hubic/Account')
hubic_account_iface = dbus.Interface(hubic_account_obj, 
'com.hubic.account')
[status, isPublished, canBePublished] = 
hubic_account_iface.GetItemStatus(filepath)
```